# v-html attribute doesn't update

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I've been pulling my hair out trying to see why this does not work, as I thought if I modified an attribute in a Vue instance, the two-way data binding takes over and will automatically be updated in the view.

I have a Laravel `Reply` model, that accepts markdown text into it's `body` attribute. I then convert this `body` attribute into raw HTML using a Laravel accessor:

Reply.php

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'parsed_body',
];

/**
 * Returns the ticket description parsed from markdown.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getParsedBodyAttribute()
{
    return Markdown::convertToHtml($this->body);
}
```

Then I have a reply component that accepts all the `Reply`s attributes into a property:

Reply.vue:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['attributes'],

        data() {
            return {
                editing: false,
                body: this.attributes.body,
                parsed_body: this.attributes.parsed_body
            };
        },

        methods: {
            update(url) {
                axios.post(url, {
                    _method: 'patch',
                    body: this.body
                }).then(response => function () {
                    this.body = response.body;
                    this.parsed_body = response.parsed_body;
                });

                this.editing = false;
            },

            destroy() {
                axios.delete('/replies/' + this.attributes.id);

                $(this.$el).fadeOut(300, () => {
                    flash('Your reply has been deleted.');
                });
            }
        },

        computed: {
            parsed: function () {
                return this.parsed_body;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My view:

```
<ticket-reply :attributes="{{ $reply }}" inline-template v-cloak>
    <div class="reply-markdown-body" v-if="editing">

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="body" rows="6" class="form-control" required v-model="body"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button
                class="btn btn-info"
                @click="update('{{ route('tickets.replies.update', [$ticket->id, $reply->id]) }}')">
                Save
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" @click="editing = false">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="reply-body" v-else v-html="parsed_body"></div>
</ticket-reply>
```

My controller (once the reply is updated):

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) return response($reply);
```

When I call the update method, the body of edit input is successfully updated and I can see the text I've added in the textarea, however when not editing, the `parsed_body` attribute isn't updated, even though I'm setting the attribute inside the update method?

When I refresh the page, I get all the correct updated content, but it's not updated dynamically like it should be?

Everything works like it should. When the update is successfully made, the edit form disappears (indicating that the attribute `this.editing` has been successfully updated), then `this.body` attribute is updated with the `v-model` binding, but **not** the `v-html` attribute??

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like `this` is your problem: you're referring to `this` inside a (non-arrow) `function` in your `then`. Do you mean to have the `function` keyword in there?

```
   methods: {
        update(url) {
            axios.post(url, {
                _method: 'patch',
                body: this.body
            }).then(response => function () {
                this.body = response.body;
                this.parsed_body = response.parsed_body;
            });

            this.editing = false;
        },
```

Comment: Unfortunately using a normal function (non-es6) doesn't work either.

Comment: Look at your code: you're using an arrow function to return a non-arrow function.

Comment: Yup I understand that, I fixed this after I posted and assigned the Vue instance a local variable to use it inside the axios `then()` promise, but that still doesn't resolve the issue. You can test this yourself in jsbin or something similar, the v-html directive doesn't seem to have any two way binding.

Comment: `v-html` is a one-way binding: you change it in the model, and it is reflected in the view. You should update your question to show the code you're using.